# force to change parent component's state by triggering action from child component

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

I have a functional component and fetch some data in order to populate my state like this:

```js
const [data, setdata] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/data", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      res
        .json()
        .then((res) => setdata(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [setdata]);
```

Now I have several buttons that trigger new fetch and those fetch change the data in the server that's why I watch `setdata` inside the useEffect.

```js
async function postOne() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/data", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    res
      .json()
      .then((res) => setdata(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
async function deleteOne(id) {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/data/${id}", {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    res
      .json()
      .then((res) => setdata(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Now if any child component needs to use **deleteOne** or others then I have to pass them as props. which causes nested prop drilling. So I was wondering is there any better approach to solve this problem? I was thinking to separate all those fetching functions into a `utils/API` file and call them only when they need but the only problem I face than how to reassign the parent state **(without using setData)**

---

Ok, I can pass any parameter to those methods. Then it might be thought I can easily externalize them, NO. **why?** when you click any button in the child component and change the data to the server, your parent component will not aware of it(because it didn't re-render hence useEffect didn't trigger) and it still holds the previously fetched data. Which creates the problem. Is the problem clear now?

Comment: You can pass a callback function from parent component to child component, when you have successfully get response from `deleteOne ` then call the callback function to trigger refeshData (which is re-call api to get data) in parent

Answer (score 0):

Well if your code has no relation with your component or its prop, you could just externalize it in another file, a static class would do the job I think.

Here is [an example ons tackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kpiybb?file=index.js) and here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import {MyService} from './MyService';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
        <button onClick={() => MyService.deleteOne()}>Delete one</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

MyService.js (Or .ts if you use it):

```
export class MyService {
  static deleteOne() {
    console.log('deleted !');
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand your telling but the problem is the data is tightly related with parent and the child component also. And every time I trigger any of those action which cause change in the stored data on the server. That's mean I have to fetch them again to my parent and continue this process. May I success to express my problem? @Quentin Grisel

Comment: But can't you just pass parameters to this `deleteOne ` method ? I mean I built just an example but you have to implement it your own way. If you think you can't, can you show an example of why you can't please ? (And how you implemented it could be nice if you need some refacto)

Comment: Ok I didn't properly read the end of your answer sorry ! So the question is : why don't you want to use `setData` ? It is mandatory to use it since a state is immutable. By the way, your useEffect listening to `setData` is strange for me, shouldn't it listen to `data` ? Then, if you update your state with `setState` (reseting it for example), then the useEffect will be triggered